# Is there a way to inherit only one element of CSS shorthand

Tags: css

A quick question from a css newbie here. I'm trying to reduce the size of my CSS files by using shorthand for certain properties such as padding/margins/etc. In certain cases I want to, for example, specify margin-top, margin-left, and margin-bottom, but inherit margin-right. I tried

```
margin: 10px inherit 11px 12px;
```

but that doesn't work because the CSS inherit keyword inherits all or nothing.

Is there a way to mark that one as skipped and do something like

```
margin: 10px    11px 12px;
margin-right: inherit;
```

and have CSS know that I am skipping one value in a 4-value shorthand, and not interpret it as a 3-value shorthand?

Does anyone know an easy way to get this to work? Or should I just use long-hand in cases where I don't specify all four values?
Thanks!

Comment: I was actually unaware that `inherit` won't work in shorthand for margin until I tried it. Hmm, still testing and something seems awry about this...

Answer (score 22):

If you overwrite the value, the last declaration will be ignored, so you can just do this:

```
element {
    margin: 10px 0 11px 12px;
    margin-right: inherit;
}
```

...where "0" here can be any value   * <sup>see below</sup>.

This will not work as you expect:

```
margin: 10px    11px 12px;
```

That would actually produce these values:

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 11px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-left: 11px; /* copied from margin-right's value since it's missing */
```

Just in case, note that `inherit` takes whatever value is applied to the parent element, and does not "reset" it to a "default" as is commonly thought. So, if it's an immediate child of something with `margin-right:100px`, it will inherit that value. It's a rare case you actually want to inherit a property like margin, you may be thinking it does something that it really doesn't.

**EDIT**: As I said in the comment, I wasn't aware of not being able to use `inherit` in shorthand (at the very least, for margin) until you brought this question up. I'm getting some rather strange results here, and I honestly don't know what to make of it: http://jsfiddle.net/fpHb9/1/

So, until someone else can come along and provide a better understanding of this behavior, be careful with this. It might be better to just explicitly set the margin.

**EDIT2**: I think I solved the mystery in the demo. I don't have reference handy, but it seems that since `inherit` is invalid in shorthand, using it will invalidate the entire declaration. So something like this will not work as expected:

```
margin:20px inherit 20px 20px; /* this line gets ignored completely */
margin-right:inherit;
```

So, to amend my previous statement:

> ...where "0" here can be any **valid margin width value** as documented here:
>  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties.

Forgive me for the long winded answer, you aroused my curiosity as to how this works (or doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, the OP noted in his question that `inherit` is an all-or-nothing value.

Comment: I see, I wasn't too clear on what that meant exactly. Honestly I'm still not sure, what are *you* referring/replying to in my post @BoltClock?