# border-color fails with inherit value

Tags: css, inheritance, colors, opera

I've recently found an issue with border color.

```
border-color: inherit //work
border-color: inherit transparent //fail
border-color: transparent inherit //work
border-color: inherit transparent transparent //fail
border-color: inherit transparent transparent transparent //fail
```

Why do these "first value inherit" border-color fail?

Comment: What browsers have you tried this in?

Comment: I'm using Opera 26.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails because according to the definition of [`border-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties), the keyword `inherit` is allowed only as the value of the property by itself, not as a component together with other values. This is what the description

```
    [ <color> | transparent ]{1,4} | inherit
```

means: you can have one to four components, each of which is either a color designation or the keyword `transparen`, *or* `inherit` as such.

There is an Opera bug involved, but the bug is that the value `transparent inherit` (and `transparent transparent inherit`) “works”, i.e. does what you mean, instead of doing what it *must* do by the specifications. According to CSS error processing rules, the declaration must be ignored when the value is syntactically malformed. (Chrome shares this bug with Opera, but Firefox and IE do the right thing.)

For example, to achieve what you mean by `border-color: transparent inherit` (namely setting top and bottom border color transparent, left and right border color inherited), you need to set individual border components one way or another in separate declarations, e.g.

```css
div { border-color: red }
span {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: inherit;
  border-right-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello world</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some googling it looks like the CSS inherit keyword is all-or-nothing, so it can't be used in shorthand. The results you're getting reflect the inconsistent interpretation of an 'invalid' rule.

See also: [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136350/is-there-a-way-to-inherit-only-one-element-of-css-shorthand).

You should be able to override the specific properties you want to inherit though, as long as your rule declarations are all valid. IE instead of:

```
border-color: inherit transparent;
```

You should use:

```
border-color-left: transparent;
border-color-right: transparent;
```

Unfortunately I don't think you can make it any shorter than that.

Comment: Actually, I think `inherit` value can be used in shorthand. Because this one  works `border-color: transparent transparent inherit`,but this one `border-color: inherit transparent transparent`. I'm thinking about this issue as a browser  bug.

Comment: Jukka's answer expands on this: the fact that inherit is working as long as its the last shorthand value used is actually the bug, the spec says you should be able to use either shorthand or inherit, but not both.

Comment: Jukka's answer expands on this: the fact that inherit is working as long as its the last shorthand value used is actually the bug, the spec says you should be able to use either shorthand or inherit, but not both.